# Kile: unable to access the settings under ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: kile

I have been using Kile for many years, and heavily depend on it. Recently, I updated to ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with kile version 4:2.1.3-3ubuntu1 and I am no longer able to access the settings that appeared under the pull-down menu. Settings (in the pull-down menu) simply proposes:

- System check
- List item
- Show side bar
- Show menu bar
- Toolbars shown

This means that I am no longer able to configure kate, install forward or backward search, etc. I have also removed .kde/share/config/kilerc, uninstalled kile and kate and reinstalled them. All this does not help.
PS: As mentioned above, I use kile version 4:2.1.3-3ubuntu1  Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.16
Kile: 2.1.3

Comment: Which version of kile? And here the preferences have there own menu.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure whether this is a the right place to ask this question. Maybe any of the suggestions at http://askubuntu.com/questions/223295/kile-missing-settings-dialog-after-update-to-kubuntu-12-10 help.

Comment: Oh, millions of thanks gernot. I did find the answer in the askubuntu post. Toolbar reinitialization did the job. I am grateful.